# Saving an object record using parse

Tags: java, android, parsing, pointers

I am trying to save records in a table that is linked with a pointer field to another table but cannot achieve it. Through parse web app if you copy the objectID field of the table and paste it on pointer field of the other table, automatically it links.

Below There is an example of what i was trying to do:

```
public class insertRow {

  *//Initialize parseObject*
  ParseObject Comments = new ParseObject("Comments");

 *Lets put some information on Comments table*
  Comments.put("User","user name");
  Comments.put("Subject","Subject");
  Comments.put("Description","Description");
  Comments.put("Rate",3);

  *//Here we want to link the actual record of Restaurant with the comment
  //saving the objectID of Restaurant to the pointer field in Comments*
  Comments.put("RestID","here comes ObjectID from table Restaurant");

  *//Saving data in background*
  Comments.SaveInBackground();
```

}

The first Table stores information about a Restaurant, the other stores information about Restaurant´s comments, so i want to link using a relation of one-to-many and then show all comments using fragment and a list view with an adapter.

I have been reading and searching information and docs. Just know its better to use pointers in case of storing large number of records.I will appreciate any help or tip. Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could finally get through this. Parse docs are not very clear, but using some doc and options, this is one way to save objects:

```
Comentario.put("RestID",ParseObject.createWithoutData("Restaurante",resid));
```

where:

- ResID : field at Comentario table in parse that represents a  pointer object to Restaurante table
- resid : field that contains the objectId string of the record at table Restaurante.

Hope it can help any has a similar doubts of how do it